# Jenkins MultiJob Phases share ${BUILD_TIMESTAMP}

Tags: jenkins

I have a parent jenkins multijob that calls 3 children jobs, passing to the children the same parameters the parent was built with.
Each child needs to use the same timestamp as it is a unique identifier that each child needs to search for on a webpage.

My problem is this:
When the parent is built, the "name" parameter is set to ${BUILD_TIMESTAMP}, lets call this "02201200" short for Feb 20, 12:00. Each child is called with "pass current job parameters". However, instead of each child receiving 02201200, they each receive ${BUILD_TIMESTAMP} and fetch this value again (eg 02201204).

How do I force the parent to evaluate ${BUILD_TIMESTAMP} and pass its evaluation to the children instead of the variable itself?

Comment: have you solved your problem? The current solution is not good to my scenario. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to write the value of this time stamp to a file. Then you could reference that value in subsequent jobs via the "Parameters from properties file" option. Obviously you would just keep overwriting this file every time your job sequence runs.

I used this method and also ended up generally saving all metadata (system/environment variables, jenkins parameters, and build properties, etc) into a properties file and even archived them. This approach simplifies/works around many problems I had. Now, every build has its metadata archived, for downstream jobs or later references, I can get all necessary information from this one file; no extra parameters need to be passed around.

Furthermore, if anything goes wrong, the metadata is very helpful for investigating. I would recommend this simple strategy as it has proven extremely useful to myself and my team.